# Cannot generate database from model: System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: entity-framework

I've got a weird error when trying to generate database from an EF model. I've been able to reproduce this in a simple scenario. I create a new project, a new Entity Data Model, a new Entity with just the `Id` as the Key. Then I select `Generate Database from Model`, choose my DB, click Next... and then I get the following error:

```
Encountered the following errors while processing the template
'...\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt':
Line 0, Column 0:
'Running transformations: System.EntryPointNotFoundException:
 Entry point was not found.  
at System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1.get_Count()
...
```

[image: Generate DB Error]

[image: Generate DB Error closeup]

The template file is present at the location referenced in the error message.
Tested against both **MS SQL Server Express** as well as **2008 R2**.
I am pretty sure I used the `Generate Database from Model` feature before and it worked fine, but I am not sure how long ago exactly (at least half a year). I got this error message with **EF 4.1** installed. Now I updated to version **4.2** and am still getting the same problem.
I am using **Visual Studio 2010 with SP1** installed (Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel).
Anyone seen anything like this before? Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please double check whether you have ever installed "EF 4.1 June CTP". Just uninstall EF 4.1 June CTP and reinstall 4.2.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with EF 5.0. Uninstalling EF4.1 CTP and restarting VS2012 did the trick. Many thanks, because there is not much information about this error!

Answer (score 6):

We also had this and solved the problem as follows:

In-edmx file right-click on the blank space between the agencies. Select the 'Properties'.
-In the properties window edmx, the key 'DDL Generation Template "should be changed to the value' SSDLToOracle.tt '. This was the source of the error!
(This template defines the conversion oracle. The template can be customized to convert types according to your preference)

-Change also the key 'Database generation workflow' to 'Generate Oracle via T4 (TPT). Xaml' (not to other error occurs).

I hope that resolves the error for you too!

Special thanks for this solution to Paulo Barbosa CTO at QUAY